# How to use SetInterval in react for progress bar

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a progress bar, and I need the user to wait 1 minute after a button click, I am trying to use SetInterval to mock out a percentage number to show to the user but I cant seem to get it working correctly. This is my code:

```
  handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.persist();
    this.setState({
      IPObject: {
        Name: event.target[0].value,
        IPList: event.target[1].value,
        priority: event.target[2].value,
        rule: "",
        Subnet: event.target[3].value
      }
    }, () => {
      // this.postIP(this.state.IPObject);
      setInterval(() => this.state.setCompleted(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1), 60000);

    })
```

from this As you can see I am using the SetInterval and then I call it in my Progress bar at the bottom like this:

```
    <ProgressBar bgcolor={"#6a1b9a"} completed={this.state.completed} />
```

Here is my State:

```
    interface IState {
  IPObject: IAddIP;
  setCompleted: any;
  completed: number;

}

interface IProps { }
export class Home extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      IPObject: {
        priority: "",
        IPList: "",
        rule: "",
        Name: "",
        Subnet: ""
      },
      setCompleted: 0,
      completed: 0
    }
  }
```

But this doesnt seem to be showing the percentage done. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like every time setInterval works, you're setting the Complete to some number between 0-100 with every 60 seconds. I didn't get why would you do this, because your progress will change to some random number every 60 seconds.

This should work properly;

`setInterval(() => this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, this.state.completed: this.state.completed + 1}) ), 60000);`

This will increase the percentage by one in every 60 seconds.

Comment: I seem to be getting this error: `TypeError: this.state.setCompleted is not a function`

Comment: @MohammedIsmail Sorry my bad, I edited the answer can you check that?

Comment: @MohammedIsmail So I think you are confusing the useState hook with the class components. I think you want to update the completed state but you also defined "setCompleted" which you can't use it like this. Because it's not a function

Comment: Oh okay that does make sense now